# Laravel Eager Loading - load() return null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

please, i have model user that have relation with model role

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string
    email - string


roles
    id - integer
    name - string
    description - string
```

i want to return the user the just some column from class role -just id and name-

my code is like :

```
$user = User::whereHas('role', function (Builder $query) {
                return $query->where('name', 'admin');
            })
                ->select(['id', 'email'])
                ->get();

        } 

$user->load('role:id,name');


return $user;
```

i have try to use  with(['role:id,name']) method i faced the same problem.

i get in the result

```
{"id":1,"email":"admin@gmail.com","role":null}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The pivot table between users and roles is missing - it would be great if you share your relation models too.

Answer (score 1):

Check Laravel [Eloquent Relationship documention](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) first and try this:
in your `User` Model make sure have a *one to many* relation

for **Eager Loading** use:

```
$user = User::with(['role' => function($q){
    $q->where('name','admin')
      ->select(['id', 'name']);
}])
->select(['name','email'])
->get();
```

for **Lazy Eager Loading** use:

```
$users = App\User::whereHas('role',function(Builder $q){ 
    $q->where('name','admin'); 
})->get();



$user->load(['role' => function ($q) {
    ->addSelect(['id','name']);
}]);
```

Hope this helps you out.